# not quite biconnected component in DAGs

Tags: directed-graphs, graph-connectivity

In undirected graphs, a "biconnected component" is a maximal subgraph containing no cut-vertices, that is, vertices whose deletion increases the number of connected components.

For directed graphs, I have the impression that people usually apply the definition above to the underlying undirected graph. However, I am looking for something similar, yet not quite the same:

Given a DAG G, a vertex x is a *not-quite-cut-vertex* iff for all strict ancestors s of x in G and all strict descendants t of x in G, all s-t-paths in G contain x. Further, a *not-quite-biconnected-component* of G is a maximal subgraph that is weakly connected and does not have a not-quite-cut-vertex.

In particular, the DAG G=({a,b,c,d,e},{ac,ad,bc,be,cd,ce}) has 2 biconnected components but only 1 not-quite-biconnected-component (since c is a cut-vertex but not a not-quite-cut-vertex).

**The questions are now**: Is this concept known for digraphs/DAGs? Is the decomposition into not-quite-biconnected-components unique? What is the complexity of computing the not-quite-biconnected-components?

Comment: Why is $c$ not a not-quite-cut vertex? It is contained in all paths form $b$ to $d$. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "strict ancestor" and "strict descendant"; usually that just means "ancestor/descendant other than the vertex itself".

Comment: For c to be not-quite-cut, the condition that c is in all x-y-paths must hold for *all* strict ancestors x of c and *all* strict descendants y of c.

Since b is a strict ancestor of c and e is a strict descendant of c, but c is not in all b-e-paths, c is not a not-quite-cut-node.

My apologies if the any vs all formulation is confusing, I'll reformulate to make it more clear.

Comment: The definition makes sense now, but I think it needs some extra condition to be "nice". My problem is that in the directed graph $a\to b\to c\to d\to e$, I *want* $a\to b$ to be a not-quite-biconnected component, but it's not. Instead, $a\to b\;c\to d$ and $a\to b\;d\to e$ are not-quite-biconnected components containing it. (Maybe add "weakly connected" as a condition?)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll do the edit right now.